# Elements outerHeight + px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add to the `outerHeight()` function additional pixels?

So we have a variable, that gets `.pg-sect` `s outerHeight:

```
var $section = $('.pg-sect').outerHeight();
```

And what I want is to add to the height we got additional 70 px. What would the code look alike?

```
var $section = $('.pg-sect').outerHeight() + 70px;
```

Okay, let me clarify:

I'd like to add a condition: whether the scrolling area equals to the area of .pg-sect - 100 px before an outerHeight, we do something. And the question is how to get these - 100px of the elements outerHeight

Comment: $('.pg-sect').outerHeight() + 70; You need to see the console for errors

Comment: It worked but is it possible to change the direction to outside of the element?

Comment: What do you mean by direction?

Comment: Like adding margin? at least that's how I make sense of it

Comment: Okay, let me clarify: I`d like to add a condition: whether the scrolling area equals to the area of .pg-sect - 100 px before an outerHeight, we do something. And the question is how to get these - 100px of the elements outerHeight

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or code block to show what is the exact problem?

Comment: @alexa.wa no need to add `px` if you using it in condition...just use the value itself

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQjaRL

if we reached the point equalled to -100 px before the $section and +100 px after the $section – run the code in conditions

Answer (score 0):

```
var $section = $('.pg-sect').outerHeight();

//Here you're just assigning a value rather than modifying the element itself
var $section = $('.pg-sect').outerHeight() + 70;
```

**To modify the element:**

```
var $section = $('.pg-sect').outerHeight() + 70;
$('.pg-sect').outerHeight($section);
```